# ODE exponential convergence rate

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, convergence-divergence

Say you're given the following ODE:

$x'(t) = -Px(t)-a$

where $x$ is a $nx1$ vector, $P$ is positive definite symmetric and $a$ is an $nx1$ vector. We know the equilibrium occurs at $-P^{-1}a$.

How do we show that x(t) converges to x* exponentially? i.e., how to show that

$||x(t)-x^{*}||_{2} \leq ||x(0)-x^{*} ||_{2}e^{-\lambda_{min}(P)t}$

I think the solution to the ODE is $x(t)=-P^{-1}a+e^{-Pt}x(0)$ but not sure how to proceed from there.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{dX}{dt}+P x=-a$$, it is a linear ODE with integrating factor as $e{Pt}$
SO its solution is
$$x(t)=e^{-Pt} \int-a e^{Pt} dt+C e^{-Pt} \implies x(t)=-\frac{a}{P}+C e^{-Pt}.$$at $t=0$, we have
$$x(0)=-\frac{a}{P}+C.$$
Finally we can write $$x(t)=-\frac{a}{P}+(x(0)+a/P)e^{-Pt}.$$
Note that this differs silgtly from the result obtained by OP. Given $x(0)$ one can
fix the solution. Nothing else is required to be done further.

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for how to show that ||()−∗||2≤||(0)−∗||2−()